# How to write a proper unit test case for this middleware file django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am working with django and now in a position to write unit test cases for a middleware file, views were easy since I could use a client and check with the response object. But this has become a little tricky. How do I write test cases for these two conditional statements.

```
def process_request(self, request):
    connection.set_schema_to_public()
    hostname = self.hostname_from_request(request)

    if hostname == settings.MAIN_SITE_HOST_NAME:
        return None
    elif hostname == 'tenant.test.com':
        request.tenant = request.institute = Institute.objects.get(
            domain_url=hostname, schema_name='test')

    connection.set_tenant(request.tenant)
    return None
```

Have attached the host_name_from_request method too,

```
def hostname_from_request(self, request):
    """ Extracts hostname from request. Used for custom requests filtering.
        By default removes the request's port and common prefixes.
    """
    domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
    if len(domain_parts) > 3:
        return remove_www(request.get_host().split(':')[0])
    else:
        return (request.get_host().split(':')[0])
```

While checking how to write test cases for middleware, I found [this site](http://blog.namis.me/2012/05/13/writing-unit-tests-for-django-middleware/) but I am still not sure about how to go about it in my case.

I tried something like this

```
def test_from_client(self):
    self.middleware = InstituteMiddleWare()
    self.request = Mock()
    self.request.path('/')
    self.assertIsNone(self.middleware.process_request(self.request))
```

and it said mock object has no attribute get_host

Answer (score 1):

Try using the RequestFactory class from django.test.  You can modify the host by passing SERVER_NAME in the kwargs, otherwise it defaults to 'testserver'

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
def test_from_client(self):
    self.middleware = InstituteMiddleWare()
    self.factory = RequestFactory(SERVER_NAME='tenant.test.com')

    request = self.factory.get("/")
    self.assertIsNone(self.middleware.process_request(request))
```